# The erroneous line is blank as per the LogCat. What do I do?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-asynctask, classnotfoundexception, android-logcat

Following is my first program I wrote in order to understand and practice the working of an AsyncTask. It is a program which downloads an image from the internet in a worker thread and displays it in an imageview in the main thread ofcourse. 
From my limited knowledge of reading LogCats, I examined the LogCat and found the phrase "Caused by: ClassNotFoundException..." and after that I ended up concluding that it is at line number 56.

1.First, please tell me if I am right in reading the LogCat? If so, line number 56 is blank :-S

1. Secondly please tell me whatever you think is wrong with this app?
   Thank you in advance.

   UsingAsyncTask.java:-

   ```
   package com.example.concurrency;

   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.net.URL;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.ImageView;

   public class UsingAsyncTask extends Activity {
   ImageView imageView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.using_asynctask); 
       String spec="http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F7%2F7a%2FBasketball.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ABasketball.png&h=340&w=340&tbnid=EJmjEDyJzrhAuM%3A&zoom=1&docid=C_hn8nOgsGmuwM&hl=en&ei=Q0o2U93LNcaIygH4mICQBQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CHwQhBwwBg&iact=rc&dur=3875&page=1&start=0&ndsp=14";
       URL params = null;
       try {params= new URL(spec);} catch(Exception e) {}
       //Bitmap result;
       new MyTask().execute(params);
       imageView= new ImageView(null);
   }
   //03015583738

   private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {

       private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String url){
           try {
           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
           return bitmap;
           } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }

       /*protected void onPreExecute() {

       }*/


       protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params){
           //if(isCancelled()) return;
           String url=params[0].toString();
           final Bitmap bitmap= loadImageFromNetwork(url);
           return bitmap;
       }

       /*protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress progress){
           setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
       }*/

       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
           imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
       }

   }

   }
   ```

LogCat:-

```
04-03 05:17:21.752: D/AndroidRuntime(1447): Shutting down VM
04-03 05:17:21.752: W/dalvikvm(1447): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 

(group=0xb1ab2ba8)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): Process: com.example.concurrency, PID: 1447
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 

instantiate activity ComponentInfo

{com.example.concurrency/com.example.concurrency.UsingAsyncTask.java}: 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 

"com.example.concurrency.UsingAsyncTask.java" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 

"/data/app/com.example.concurrency-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-

lib/com.example.concurrency-1, /system/lib]]
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at 

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at 

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800

(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread

$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage

(Handler.java:102)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main

(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative

(Native Method)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke

(Method.java:515)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit

$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 

Method)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

Didn't find class "com.example.concurrency.UsingAsyncTask.java" on path: DexPathList[[zip 

file "/data/app/com.example.concurrency-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-

lib/com.example.concurrency-1, /system/lib]]
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at 

dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass

(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass

(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity

(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at 

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-03 05:17:21.782: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     ... 11 more
04-03 05:17:26.782: I/Process(1447): Sending signal. PID: 1447 SIG: 9
```

Manifest file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.concurrency"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.concurrency.UsingAsyncTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the launcher activity's name in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `.UsingAsyncTask`. It's `MainActivity` currently, which seems to be missing.

Moreover, you don't have to manually find the line when it is mentioned in the LogCat. Just double-clicking the right line in Eclipse's LogCat view will automatically jump to the corresponding line in your code.

Comment: Nothing changed except the name of the class in the LogCat. I am updating the LogCat in the question.